# How to sum data from multiple rows and columns according to unique search key in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sequence, vlookup

I am trying to sum the average total sales of each employee in [this table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m7HkVC8VB1IQ8vPoZB98_f6Nd75-Fv3KP32Ohp5QYVY/edit?usp=sharing). For example, Tim sold ten vehicles day 1, nine day 2, and eleven day 3, for an average of 10 per day. I tried using vlookup at first but this will only grab the first search_key, so because Tim shows up 3 times, I only get the result of the first day. Is there a way to use a similar function to vlookup (maybe filter?) to grab all of the columns each time the employee's name shows up, then average the total sales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:A10, MMULT(C2:E10*1, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(C2:E10), 1, 1, ))}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this worked exactly like I wanted! For future reference, what does the "1, 1," refer to in "SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(C2:E10), 1, 1, ))"?

Comment: @SheetsAsker99 means:  1 column, start from 1, step by 0 (zero is neglected)